# Using ptr_vector with malloc

Tags: c++, c, boost

Can `ptr_vector` be used with `malloc` that can automatically free the memory?

The reason I am asking because, I have to push pointer to a structure inside the `ptr_vector` object.

Comment: No it can't. Also, why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: If its not, then could you please suggest some way to store pointer object and I dont need to worry about freeing them .

Comment: What do you mean by *used with malloc that can automatically free the memory*? You can implement your own allocator that uses `malloc` & `free` and create a [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) that uses your allocator

Comment: Recently I came across  shared_ptr and found that it can be used with malloc also
like this.....
    
    `boost::shared_ptr<Employee_t> srdpointer((Employee_t*)malloc(sizeof(Employee_t)),std::ptr_fun(free));`           
      I want to know if the same can be used with ptr_vector that can store multiple pointer objects.

Comment: @omsarathe That approach will fail miserably if `Employee_t` has a user-defined non-trivial constructor and / or destructor. malloc & free do not call an object's constructor and destructor, while new and delete do. Why do you want to use malloc instead of new?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `boost::ptr_vector` it's by design, but you need to use C++ `new` statement instead of old good C `malloc()/free()`. See example:

```
struct S { int i; double d; };
boost::ptr_vector<S> pv;

// pv now owns dynamic S instance and will destroy it when going out of scope
pv.push_back(new S());
pv[0].i = 42; // Using it as usual
```

There are also ways to define your own allocator compatible with `std::allocator` so it will use `malloc()/free()` but looks like it's not that you actually need.

Comment: @Prætorian/Rost. Do you mean I can write my own allocator based on malloc and free , and that will work out. If possible could you please provide some sample code.

Comment: @omsarathe You still haven't explained why you want use malloc instead of new

Comment: @omsarathe E.g. see this acticle on [std::allocator implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement)

Comment: Our application is a mix of C and C++ code which uses lot of C Structures. So We cannot use new with structures

Comment: @omsarathe Actually typical C++ operator `new` implementation will use `malloc` to allocate memory. So why do you need to reinvent the wheel again?

Comment: @omsarathe If you compile it under C++ you CAN use `new` for C structs.

Comment: Please forgive me , if the question looks silly to you but I thought new and malloc are different. Anyway I have got my answer and your help is much appreciated . Thank you guys

Comment: @Rost: You can not assume that (there is no guarantee that new will use malloc).

Comment: @omsarathe They are different, you are right. But typical `new/delete` impl (not guaranteed, but on most compilers) is type safe wrapper under `malloc/free` that also provides additional functionality - C++ class construction/destruction. But nothing prevents you from using `new` with "plain old data" that are C structs. Or any other C type - `int`, `double`, `char` etc. Just match allocation/deallocation - if you use `new` - deallocate with `delete`, not `free`. Or even better always use smart pointers - they deallocate memory automatically.

Comment: @Loki Astari - yes, if speaking strictly. But do you know any standard impl where it is not true? By the way, edited comment to get rid of such assumption.

Comment: @Roost: Yes several. Doing so makes your code completely unportable. Just because the two major implementations do MSVC and g++ does not make it universal. With addition of smart phones as a standard platform over the last few years has turned a lot of assumptions (like what other implementations don't do this) on their head. We wrote a lot of bad code in the 80/90 that made lots of assumptions now all that code is breaking. We have learned and best engineering practice is that just because I am not smart enough to see the future does not mean I can make life harder for the maintainer.

Comment: @LokiAstari Agree. By the way, I don't suggest to write any code that assumes the `new` is using `malloc`. Just briefly explaining how does it look like.